# Apache NiFi: UpdateRecord processor retunrs java.lang.NumberFormatException error

Tags: apache-nifi

Asking a question, there is a problem while sending e-commerce information to BigQuery in a csv file. In csv, the value of the `ORDER_DATE` column should go into the `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` format in the `DATETIME` type column in the BigQuery, tried to find some references on Google.

#### Environment

- Apache NiFi 1.14.0 on Docker

#### Attempt1

**Replacement Value Strategy** was selected to **Literal Value**, and`/ORDER_DATE` was added as a new field. The value is as follows:

```java
${field.value:toDate('yyyyMMddhhmmss','GMT'):format('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss', 'GMT')}
```

Symptom is below:
[image]

#### Attempt2

Found a new reference, that the NiFi expression was wrong, so I did another way:

```java
${field.value:equals('0'):ifElse('', ${field.value:replace(${field.value},${field.value:toDate('yyyyMMddHHmmss'):format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'):toString()})})}
```

Likewise symptom is below:
[image]

Someone asked me to open the log, checked and it's as follows:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2022-01-08 15:22:17"

Any ideas? Thank you :)

Comment: In which format and timezone are you getting `ORDER_DATE ` value?

Comment: Can you include a sample of what your SOURCE data looks like BEFORE the UpdateRecord? Are you sure `yyyyMMddHHmmss` is the correct date format of the input data?

Comment: @VikramsinhShinde Not included timezone, just formatted `yyyyMMddHHmmss`, e.g., `20211221161900`
@Sdairs Yes, it's definitely a 14 digit number in the `yyyyMMddHHmmss` format

Comment: I think the best way to troubleshoot is to validate upstream CSV data using either `ValidateCsv` or `ValidateRecord`. This will capture any invalid records that do not conform to the way you are expecting the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem using `UpdateRecord` without adding to upstream `ValidateCSV`.

In controller services, `CSVReader` and `CSVRecordSetWriter` were modified as follows:

- Changed property `Schema Access Strategy` of processor `CSVReader` to `User String Fields From Header`
- Changed all properties to the default of processor `CSVRecordSetWriter`

Here are the test results:

- In `GenerateFlowFile`, the following text to change to format `yyyyMMddHmmss` was made into csv
  [image]
- NiFi expressions to be modified in `UpdateRecord`
  [image]
- `CSVRecordSetWriter` left the default setting and set `CSVReader` as follows
  [image]
- After completing the above setting, the value may be converted without an error
  [image]

Searched to see the file in the error log and found the cause. It seemed to be inferred as type string, but it was type float, resulting in the above error.

Thank you for your comments. @VikramsinhShinde @Sdairs